# Optimal rsync options for moving home directory

Tags: linux, rsync, file-copy, home

I am on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine and in preparation for an upgrade to 18.04 LTS I want to move all `/home` directories (in fact there is only `/home/juergen`) to a separate, now free partition that I happen to have.

I found two good tutorials on how to do this correctly, namely

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

and (in German)

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Home_umziehen/

I understand them fully, but have a question about the optimal set of options to use for moving the home directory data.

The first source recommends

```
sudo rsync -aXS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.
```

the second one

```
rsync -avxH --progress /home/ /mnt/tmp
```

I understand that the `--exclude` from the first source is reasonable and `--progress` from the second one too and that they can be combined. But what about the other options? `S` (preserving sparsity) seems to be useful as I generated artificially for some test purposes some very big 'files with holes' in my home-directory. `H` (hard links) looks worthwhile too - or could it be a problem to preserve hard-links? `X` seems also good: as I want to preserve everything and this promises to preserve 'extended attributes' (whatever this means). So should I simply combine them all?

But even then there might be some options lurking, that would be useful? I must admit I can not come to a clear conclusion with all these `rsync` options (in my own backups I use `rsync -avzu`).

Many thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

> So should I simply combine them all?

Yes. You could also add `A`, `U` and `H` for good measure, so the net result will be `sudo rsync -aXSAUH --progress --preallocate source/ destination`.

The `--preallocate` option is very nice IMO because it avoids file fragmentation.

**Comparing the checksums of the original and destination files is also hugely recommended**. At least I always do that to avoid probable interface errors. There are multiple ways to do that, including `diff`, `cmp`, `find/xargs/md5sum`, etc.

---

Personally I'd use `e2image` because `rsync` cannot copy file creation times. Also, copying an image is almost always a lot faster than copying individual files.

Here's an example:

```
e2image -rap /dev/source_partition /dev/destination_partition
```

The meaning of these options can be found in `man e2image`. You will need to remount the `source_partition` `ro` before running this command. There are other options as well: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_cloning

---

Lastly you could delete everything except `/home` in your `/` folder and simply install new Ubuntu into a new partition - that's my personal favorite because your data will be untouched and `/` doesn't actually take a lot of space.

Comment: If I understand your example correctly, it would be necessary, that /home is already in a separate partition before the copy. Unfortunately as things now are, /home is just a directory in a big / partition (as I used Ubuntu defaults on installing).

Comment: I found no option -U (did you mean -u)?

Comment: Maybe my `rsync` is newer than yours, cause `man rsync` here says `--atimes, -U             preserve access (use) times`.

Comment: Maybe, I have, rsync  version 3.1.1  protocol version 31 (from rsync --help). I will think about yout proposal, to use the new partition as the root for a new installation. The main problem with this for me is, that I have lots of packages added to the default installation and need a way to migrate them to a new Ubuntu version, so that I considered the 'upgrade' way as the only possible.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm This might be what you're looking for: https://askubuntu.com/a/37704 Installing fresh is almost always safer than updating even for Linux.

Comment: You should have good backups, so a new install becomes easy when (not if) hard drive fails or user error destroys your current install.  Most important are /home & the list of installed apps as posted above. If you change system settings those are in /etc (I only change a few files & just copy those into /home for normal backup). And if any server type apps that would be in / like data base or web.

Comment: You have to be careful with `--preallocate` because when copying sparse files (e.g. virtual machine images), space for the whole file gets reserved. The option can be useful, but I would not recommend it for copying /home.

Comment: @ManuelJacob People normally never use sparse files. I've had zero on my home PC for the past 25 years. I've had zero on my >200 servers.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I’ve searched my home directory and found some sparse files: sqlite databases (used by Firefox and Thunderbird), virtual machine images (for which keeping the sparseness is important, as they are very big), and others. I agree that it wouldn’t matter for most people, unless they have virtual machine images. However, since this question was about moving data to a fresh partition, file fragmentation won’t be a problem even without `--preallocate`, so I would not recommend including the option by default for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

I would do `rsync -aPHAXS source dest` if it were me. But you also talk about moving them and `rsync` copies so maybe just `mv` is enough?

Comment: Actually I do not know this, but I think 'mv' would destroy a lot of properties associated with a file, especially times - or is this untrue?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use the `-P/--partial` option. Using `mv` is really not recommended. This command is not safe from too many points of view.